# How to make use of a single label so that if you click it multiple times the following controls will show?

Tags: c#, winforms, label

I'm making a visual novel type of game with Windows Forms, and I have this feature wherein at the bottom-right corner of the form, there's a label with the text "Click this message to continue". I wanted to find a shorter way such that I can only use a single label to move on to the next sequence (such as displaying the next text in a textBox).

I've tried putting multiple labels on top of one another, then if a label is already clicked, I would just make its visible property be false for the next sequence.

```
        private void LblContinue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lbl1.Visible = false;
            lbl2.Visible = true;
            charIndex = 0;
            lbl2.Text = string.Empty;
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.TypewriteText2));
            t.Start();
            lblContinue.Visible = false;
        }

        private void LblContinue2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lbl2.Visible = false;
            lbl3.Visible = true;
            charIndex = 0;
            lbl3.Text = string.Empty;
            Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.TypeWriteText3));
            t.Start();
            lblContinue2.Visible = false;
        }
```

Although this method works, I expect that for example, a text in a textBox will display "Hello" then after clicking the `lblContinue` it then displays "World" then after clicking it again it displays "Everyone". Don't mind the other codes, I would like to put emphasis on the `lblContinue.Visible` and `lblContinue2.Visible`.

Comment: Strange fragment: `lbl2.Visible = true; charIndex = 0; lbl2.Text = string.Empty;` you show an empty (no text) label

Comment: It's for the threading function since I wanted to animate the text such that it will type itself when it displays.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use one label and some other variable like an `int` to keep track of the state.  Each time you click the label, check the current state and alter the text accordingly.  Something similar to this:

```
    string[] states = { "Hello", "World", "Everyone" };
    int currentState = 0;

    private void stateLabel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        stateLabel.Text = states[currentState];

        //Select next state
        currentState++;
        if (currentState >= states.Length)
        {
            currentState = 0;
        }
    }
```